# Cannot Set ActiveRecord ID in Test Environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

In my `before_create` callback I **CAN** assign my custom GUID in the production and development environments. However, the same code running in the test environment **CANNOT** change the value of my custom GUID. See code example below.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'uuidtools'
require 'base32/crockford'

class WhatClass < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Declare the non-standard column guid as the primary key
  set_primary_key :guid
  # Use a callback to generate the record id
  before_create :create_uuid

  private
    # This method creates a universally unique identifier (UUID)
    # for an instance of WhatClass. This method is called before the
    # record is created.
    def create_uuid
      # Create the UUID
      uuid = UUIDTools::UUID.sha1_create(UUIDTools::UUID_URL_NAMESPACE, "string-to-create-from")
      self.guid = Base32::Crockford.encode(uuid.to_i)
    end
end
```

Can someone please explain why `self.guid` works in production/development but not in test?